# MS Project 2007 - resource leveling part time resource

Tags: microsoft-project, microsoft-project-2007

I am working on a project plan where I have a resource available 1.5 hrs / day (so have set their "max. units" at 12.5% to represent this).  Some of the tasks in the plan are over 1.5 hrs however (e.g. 3hrs), so when I try to do automatic resource leveling Project complains that 3hrs is > 1.5hrs and won't do it.  What I want it to do is realize that the 3hr task will take two 1.5 hr days.  I don't want to artificially break down 3hr tasks into two 1.5hr tasks either.

How do I get resource leveling to work like this?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.  Created a custom calendar with 1.5hrs/day for the resource & put max units back to 100%.  Leveling then worked as expected.